# feedparser object has no attribute 'etag' and 'modified'

Tags: python, feedparser

I am trying to run example from [feedparser documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/feedparser/http-etag.html)

What I have tried so far

```
import feedparser
d = feedparser.parse('http://feedparser.org/docs/examples/atom10.xml')
print d.etag
```

I am getting this error for **etag**

> AttributeError: object has no attribute 'etag'

I have also tried

```
print d.modified
```

Same error

> AttributeError: object has no attribute 'modified'

```
print d
```

gives me this

```
{'feed': {'summary': u''}, 'status': 302, 'version': u'', 'encoding': u'utf-8', 'bozo': 1, 'headers': {'content-length': '333', 'content-encoding': 'gzip', 'age': '1', 'expires': '-1', 'vary': 'Accept-Encoding', 'server': 'Microsoft-IIS/7.5', 'connection': 'close', 'pragma': 'no-cache', 'cache-control': 'no-cache', 'date': 'Tue, 19 Sep 2017 06:39:58 GMT', 'x-powered-by': 'ASP.NET', 'content-type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8', 'x-aspnet-version': '4.0.30319'}, 'href': u'http://feedparser.org/docs/examples/atom10.xml', 'namespaces': {}, 'entries': [], 'bozo_exception': SAXParseException('no element found',)}
```

There is no **etag** or **modified** key here. What am I missing?

Comment: Seems like the `http://feedparser.org/docs/examples/atom10.xml` no longer exist. Well more like the whole domain. Try accessing it from your browser.

Comment: @PacoH. You are right. The domain no longer exist. Now I have tried this [dummy url](http://www.feedforall.com/sample.xml). Got both **etag** and **modified**.